# How to control access to MPEG-DASH streaming?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, mpeg-dash

How would one approach authorization or access control to an mpeg-dash video streaming resource?

Is authorization provided within the standard itself? I've seen mention of having the need for a license server or things like Widevine and Encryption? Would authorization require implementing DRM.

Would it be possible to use JWT (session) token for access to the MPD and/or to the segment files themselves?

Would it be possible to have an api serve the MPEG-DASH resources?

Comment: Depends on the level of protection needed. A signed url may be enough for your use case, or you may need full DRM.